# Getting new outputs after adding a Keras Lambda layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

In the following code, I have `XE`, `XW`, `YE`, and `YW` of shapes `(474077, 32)`, `(474077, 32)`, `(474077, 1)`, and `(474077, 1)`, respectively.

After separately training `modelE` and `modelW` on 32 inputs and 1 output each, I add a `Lambda` layer that minimizes the difference between the outputs of both models. This code ran without errors.

I'm assuming this `Lambda` layer updates the weights and biases of `modelE` and `modelW` to minimize the difference between their outputs. How do I use the new updated weights and biases of `modelE` and `modelW` to predict their new outputs? I want to compare the initial outputs of the models and their outputs after the `Lambda` layer minimized the difference between them.

```
XtrainE, XtestE, YtrainE, YtestE = train_test_split(XE, YE, test_size=.5)
XtrainW, XtestW, YtrainW, YtestW = train_test_split(XW, YW, test_size=.5)

modelE = Sequential()
modelE.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', input_dim=32)) 
modelE.add(Dense(20, activation='relu')) 
modelE.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

modelW = Sequential()
modelW.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', input_dim=32)) 
modelW.add(Dense(20, activation='relu')) 
modelW.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

modelE.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
modelW.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

historyE= modelE.fit(XtrainE, YtrainE, validation_data=(XtestE,YtestE), epochs=200, batch_size=100, verbose=1)
historyW= modelW.fit(XtrainW, YtrainW, validation_data=(XtestW,YtestW), epochs=200, batch_size=100, verbose=1)

YpredE = modelE.predict(XtestE)  
YpredW = modelW.predict(XtestW)

difference = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] - x[1])([modelE.output, modelW.output])
diffModel = Model(modelE.inputs + modelW.inputs, difference)
diffModel.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='mse')
diffModel.fit([XE,XW], np.zeros(YE.shape), epochs=200, batch_size=100, verbose=1)
```

I tried:

```
YpredWnew = modelW.predict(XtestW)
YpredEnew = modelE.predict(XtestE)
for i in range (len(YpredWnew)):
    print("oldE= %.2f, newE= %.2f, oldW= %.2f, newW= %.2f," % (YpredE[i], YpredWnew[i], YpredW[i], YpredWnew[i]))
```

but this gives back the same value for all `i` in `YpredEnew[i]`

Thanks

Comment: You mean `YpredE[i] == YpredEnew[i]` or all the values in `YpredEnew` are the same?

Comment: No, all the values are = 1.0537044 for some reason